# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS BCM43142 HP pavilion 14 Wifi strength too weak

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, drivers, broadcom

I am new to ubuntu and installed **ubuntu 14.04** 5 days back.**Everything was working fine** including wifi.

I **reinstalled ubuntu** and now am having **problem with wifi**.It is connected but **signal is too weak**.It is 1/10th of speed in windows 7.

I have **gone through various questions** similar,but  to **no avail**.

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by upgrading my kernel by typing this in terminal: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

```
  sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y && \
  sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean
```